# Can you upload your own music?

Tags: watch-dogs

While driving cars, you can listen to music being played or not. Can you somehow upload your own choice of music? It would be funny if you could play Taylor Swift's "Shake it off" while being chased by the police.

Another question, can you get the game's music?

Comment: You can always turn up your own radio!

Comment: On a related note: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WH_Vod6aLqg

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unlike in Grand Theft Auto, this is unfortunately not supported in Watch Dogs.

Comment: how about getting the music/s from the game?

Comment: @ken consider asking that as its own question.